# AMI EC2 or UserData Script for automated web application deployment with Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a web application running on an Apache web server and a MySQL database (i'm using RDS for that) in addition to AutoScaling group and LoadBalancer.

I'm actually writing a complete template in Cloudformation for the deployment and my question is what's the best practice to integrate the customisation of the application and the webserver?

I mean do i have to create a custom AMI that contains all the packages installed and other customized plugins and configurations or create a UserData script that will be executed when a new EC2 instance in launched ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Either option would work but since your using AutoScaling I would recommend creating a custom AMI.

**Pros:**

1. You will have the same image every time you scale up. Installing from a script could provide new instances that have different software versions.  That can turn into a troubleshooting nightmare.
2. It's faster to have your software pre-loaded.
3. Allows for a structured Blue/Green Deployment

**Cons:**

1. Static images are outdated as soon as they are created.

Comment: Is it possible to combine Containers with the use of AMIs ? Containers will have the same software version and environment. For example a container with an Apache webserver and a specific installed version of PHP ?

Comment: Sure it would be possible.  I'd recommend using the AWS ECS-optimized AMI's.  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html)